# Creating a copy of a sheet by copying values only?

Tags: google-sheets

I use the below script to basically duplicate an existing worksheet. The worksheet I am copying contains the ImportRange. I don't want the copy spreadsheet to have the formula just the value from the field on the original worksheet. Is there a way of specifying that the inserted sheet only inserts values?

```
function newSheet() {
  var sheetName = formatDate();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MeetingTemplate");
  ss.insertSheet(sheetName, 4, {template: templateSheet}); 
}

function formatDate() {
  var month, day, d = new Date();
  month = ('0'+(d.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
  day = ('0'+d.getUTCDate()).slice(-2);
  return d.getUTCFullYear()+'-'+month+'-'+day;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the last line of the first function,

```
ss.insertSheet(sheetName, 4, {template: templateSheet});
```

with the following:

```
var sheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetName, 4, {template: templateSheet}); 
sheet.getDataRange().copyTo(sheet.getDataRange(), {contentsOnly:true});
```

Here, the first line gets the reference to the inserted sheet. The second line uses [`copyTo`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,Object)) to copy the inserted sheet into itself, but pasting only the values.